# Updating text in real time in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently i'm  in a beginners python class, making christmas cards to learn how to use tkinter to draw stuff. What I want to figure out is how to make it so that my signature is written directly into the card itself, not in a input window, and allow me to hit backspace and delete stuf if i make a typo. Then when I press enter, it locks in the code and stops allowing the user to input. Here's the current, hideous code.

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title('At the \'Sell Your Soul!\' shop, batteries are NOT included.')
c=Canvas(window,height=500,width=500)
c.pack()


background=c.create_rectangle(500,500,1,1,fill='red')
line1=c.create_text(250,50,text='Are you tired of being a mere mortal monster?')
titleline=c.create_text(250,10,text='SELL YOUR SOUL HERE!')
line2=c.create_text(250,100,text='Hate having to wait for the \'hero\'s permenant seal against evil\' to break?')
line3=c.create_text(250,150,text='Well, you\'re in luck! Here, at D. Advocates Inc, we\'ll fight for your right to be free!')
line4=c.create_text(250,200,text='All for the low, low price of your eternal soul bound in servitude!')
line5=c.create_text(250,250,text='Sign now, and we\'ll give you an amazing financing rate! 0% for the rest of your \'Life\'!')
line6=c.create_text(250,300,text='You\'ll be resurrected instantly, ready to commit any atrocities and crimes you can think of!')
line7=c.create_text(250,350,text='Revived long after the fall of your evil empire? Don\'t worry, we have that covered, too!')
line9=c.create_text(250,400,text='We\'ll teach you the new language free! That\' right, free! Stop waiting, and sign today!')
line8=c.create_line(250,450,450,450)
xline=c.create_text(255,445,text='X',fill='White')
noguarentee=c.create_text(250,490,text='No guarentees expressed or implied. No refunds, only store credit. Batteries not Included.')
signhere=c.create_text(350,460,text='Sign \'your name\' here.')
signature=c.create_text(350,440,text='your name',fill='white',font=('Edwardian Script ITC',30),state=HIDDEN)
def signing(event):
    c.itemconfig(signature,state=NORMAL)
    c.itemconfig(xline,state=HIDDEN)
c.bind_all('<KeyPress-x>', signing)
```

And if I'm correct, the code I need to enter for signing is something like this, right?

```
allowtyping=True
while allowtyping==True:
    *allow for typing code here*
def signed(event):
    allowtyping=False
c.bind_all('<KeyPress-Enter>', signed)
```

Comment: Provide more info and edit your question. Right now, it is extremely confusing!

Comment: How do you expect to know when the user is done signing? When they press enter? Click a button? Pause for X seconds?

Comment: As soon as they press enter, the signature is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, I've created an entry field and confirm button that the user enters their signature into. When they press the confirm button, it destroys the button and entry field, and puts their entered signature into the canvas:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title('At the \'Sell Your Soul!\' shop, batteries are NOT included.')
c=Canvas(window,height=500,width=500)
c.pack()

def lockSig():
    enteredSig = signhere.get()

    confirmSign.destroy()
    signhere.destroy()

    c.itemconfig(signature, state=NORMAL, text=enteredSig)

background=c.create_rectangle(500,500,1,1,fill='red')
line1=c.create_text(250,50,text='Are you tired of being a mere mortal monster?')
titleline=c.create_text(250,10,text='SELL YOUR SOUL HERE!')
line2=c.create_text(250,100,text='Hate having to wait for the \'hero\'s permenant seal against evil\' to break?')
line3=c.create_text(250,150,text='Well, you\'re in luck! Here, at D. Advocates Inc, we\'ll fight for your right to be free!')
line4=c.create_text(250,200,text='All for the low, low price of your eternal soul bound in servitude!')
line5=c.create_text(250,250,text='Sign now, and we\'ll give you an amazing financing rate! 0% for the rest of your \'Life\'!')
line6=c.create_text(250,300,text='You\'ll be resurrected instantly, ready to commit any atrocities and crimes you can think of!')
line7=c.create_text(250,350,text='Revived long after the fall of your evil empire? Don\'t worry, we have that covered, too!')
line9=c.create_text(250,400,text='We\'ll teach you the new language free! That\' right, free! Stop waiting, and sign today!')
line8=c.create_line(250,450,450,450)
xline=c.create_text(255,445,text='X',fill='White')
noguarentee=c.create_text(250,490,text='No guarentees expressed or implied. No refunds, only store credit. Batteries not Included.')

signhere= Entry(window, text='Sign \'your name\' here.')
signhere.place(x=280,y=430)

confirmSign = Button(window, text='Confirm', command=lockSig)
confirmSign.place(x=280, y=450)

signature=c.create_text(350,440,text='your name',fill='white',font=('Edwardian Script ITC',30),state=HIDDEN)
```

Alternatively, you can use this line (which would be placed above the creation of the button):

```
window.bind('<Return>',lockSig)
```

and edit the lockSig function to:

```
def lockSig(event):
    enteredSig = signhere.get()

    confirmSign.destroy()
    signhere.destroy()

    c.itemconfig(signature, state=NORMAL, text=enteredSig)
```

This way you will be able to get rid of the button, and is more what you were asking for.

Hope this helps!